# Don't include parent folder when packing tar

Tags: javascript, node.js, tar

I created a build system as an npm script, so I'm able to run `npm run build -- <DIRECTORY>`. This runs the file `build.js`, which packs a couple of tar archives from the specified directory and moves the resulting tar into the `dist` directory.

For this I use the package [`node-tar`](https://github.com/npm/node-tar):

```
var stream = fstream.Reader({ 
  path: project + "/" + folder
});

stream.pipe(tar.Pack())
  .pipe(fstream.Writer({ path: project + "/" + folder + ".tar" }));
```

Assume the following directory structure:

```
folder-a
  test1.xml
  test2.xml
dist
package.json
build.js
```

When running `npm run build -- folder-a`, this should create a tar-archive with the contents of folder-a with the following structure:

```
folder-a.tar
  test1.xml
  test2.xml
```

What it does though, is the following:

```
folder-a.tar
  folder-a
    test1.xml
    test2.xml
```

How can I get rid of the parent directory and put the files directly into the root of the archive?

Comment: Have you tried passing `{fromBase: true}` into `tar.Pack()`? I mean that’s what the README suggests: https://github.com/npm/node-tar#tarpackproperties.

Comment: Stupid me missed to read that option... Thanks, that was it! :)