# Don't include absolute path to archive with node-tar

Tags: javascript, node.js, tar

I have a dir with a number of dirs and files inside, which I want add to tar.
I use [node-tar](https://github.com/npm/node-tar) package for it. I am passing it two params: source and destination strings after `path.resolve` exec. Finally I have tar.gz, which includes absolute path before my target.

Here's what I did:

```
const path = require('path');
const tar = require('tar');
const { promisify } = require('util');
const tarCreateAsync = promisify(tar.c);

const src = path.resolve(__dirname, 'test-data');
const dst = path.resolve(__dirname, 'output-data');

async function addToTar(src, dst) {
    await tarCreateAsync(
        {
            gzip: true,
            file: path.resolve(dst, 'static.tgz'),
        },
        [src]
    )
}

addToTar(src, dst);
```

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33055288/dont-include-parent-folder-when-packing-tar?newreg=80d5fa8b652343d3998eac8dcb6cbec2) article, but the API has been changed and the anchor shows nothing.

Also tried with `preservePaths` option but no effect

Answer (score 2):

Solve it, it's been `C` or `cwd` option for set base path value.

It's look like this

```
    await tarCreateAsync(
        {
            gzip: true,
            file: path.resolve(dst, 'static.tgz'),
            cwd: path.resolve(__dirname),
        },
        ['test-data']
    )
```